How to use Java's FFM API to call NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask on macOS?
I try to use Java's FFM API to call NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask on macOS.
import java.lang.foreign.*;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;
import java.util.Optional;

import static java.lang.foreign.ValueLayout.ADDRESS;
import static java.lang.foreign.ValueLayout.JAVA_LONG;

public class CocoaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            long NSEventId = (long) objcGetClass().get().invoke(Arena.global().allocateFrom("NSEvent"));

            MemorySegment addGlobalMonitorForEventsSel = (MemorySegment) selRegisterName().get()
                    .invoke(Arena.global().allocateFrom("addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:"));

            MethodHandle eventHandler = MethodHandles.lookup().findStatic(CocoaTest.class, "eventHandler",
                    MethodType.methodType(void.class, MemorySegment.class));
            MemorySegment eventHandlerMS = Linker.nativeLinker().upcallStub(eventHandler,
                    FunctionDescriptor.ofVoid(ADDRESS), Arena.global());

            objcMsgSend(FunctionDescriptor.ofVoid(
                    JAVA_LONG,
                    ADDRESS,
                    JAVA_LONG,
                    ADDRESS
            )).get().invoke(NSEventId, addGlobalMonitorForEventsSel, 1 << 6, eventHandlerMS);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static SymbolLookup foundationSymbolLookup() {
        return SymbolLookup.libraryLookup("/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation",
                Arena.global());
    }

    public static Optional<MethodHandle> objcMsgSend(FunctionDescriptor functionDescriptor) {
        return foundationSymbolLookup()
                .find("objc_msgSend")
                .map(memorySegment -> Linker.nativeLinker()
                        .downcallHandle(memorySegment, functionDescriptor));
    }

    public static Optional<MethodHandle> objcGetClass() {
        return foundationSymbolLookup()
                .find("objc_getClass")
                .map(memorySegment -> Linker.nativeLinker()
                        .downcallHandle(memorySegment, FunctionDescriptor.of(JAVA_LONG, ADDRESS)));
    }

    public static Optional<MethodHandle> selRegisterName() {
        return foundationSymbolLookup()
                .find("sel_registerName")
                .map(memorySegment -> Linker.nativeLinker()
                        .downcallHandle(memorySegment, FunctionDescriptor.of(ADDRESS, ADDRESS)));
    }

    public static void eventHandler(MemorySegment eventId) {
        System.out.println("handle handleevent...");
    }
}

This code generates an hs_err_pid3323.log file, which shows the following:
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000019fe0dc20, pid=4307, tid=10243
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 22.0.1+8.1 (22.0.1+8) (build 22.0.1+8-jvmci-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 22.0.1+8.1 (22.0.1+8-jvmci-b01, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, jvmci, jvmci compiler, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, bsd-aarch64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0x9c20]  objc_msgSend+0x20
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=1 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+EnableJVMCIProduct -XX:-UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 ffmdemo.CocoaTest

Host: "MacBookPro18,3" arm64, 10 cores, 16G, Darwin 23.5.0, macOS 14.5 (23F79)
Time: Sun Oct 20 10:51:34 2024 CST elapsed time: 0.169083 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000010c808200):  JavaThread "main"             [_thread_in_native, id=10243, stack(0x000000016bc90000,0x000000016be93000) (2060K)]

Stack: [0x000000016bc90000,0x000000016be93000],  sp=0x000000016be923d0,  free space=2056k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0x9c20]  objc_msgSend+0x20
C  [AppKit+0x3314e4]  -[_NSGlobalEventObserver initMatchingEvents:handler:]+0x2c
C  [AppKit+0x3313d8]  +[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:]+0x48
C  0xe62a000139141f44
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH+0x000007f801087000.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;JJJJJ)V+16 java.base@22.0.1
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH+0x000007f80108ac00.invokeExact_MT(Ljava/lang/Object;JJJJJLjava/lang/Object;)V+27 java.base@22.0.1
j  jdk.internal.foreign.abi.DowncallStub+0x000007f801087400.invoke(Ljava/lang/foreign/SegmentAllocator;Ljava/lang/foreign/MemorySegment;JLjava/lang/foreign/MemorySegment;JLjava/lang/foreign/MemorySegment;)V+142 java.base@22.0.1
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH+0x000007f801087c00.invokeStaticInit(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V+20 java.base@22.0.1
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH+0x000007f80108a400.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;ILjava/lang/Object;)V+72 java.base@22.0.1
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH+0x000007f801089c00.invoke_MT(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+27 java.base@22.0.1
j  com.github.yqy7.ffmdemo.CocoaTest.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+144
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub 0x0000000138ffc154
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x4b14a8]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle const&, JavaCallArguments*, JavaThread*)+0x3d8
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x52add8]  jni_invoke_static(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, JavaThread*)+0x170
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x52e430]  jni_CallStaticVoidMethod+0xfc
C  [libjli.dylib+0xa108]  invokeStaticMainWithArgs+0x94
C  [libjli.dylib+0xab90]  JavaMain+0x780
C  [libjli.dylib+0xd5e0]  ThreadJavaMain+0xc
C  [libsystem_pthread.dylib+0x6f94]  _pthread_start+0x88
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
v  ~RuntimeStub::nep_invoker_blob 0x0000000139141f0c
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH+0x000007f801087000.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;JJJJJ)V+16 java.base@22.0.1
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH+0x000007f80108ac00.invokeExact_MT(Ljava/lang/Object;JJJJJLjava/lang/Object;)V+27 java.base@22.0.1
j  jdk.internal.foreign.abi.DowncallStub+0x000007f801087400.invoke(Ljava/lang/foreign/SegmentAllocator;Ljava/lang/foreign/MemorySegment;JLjava/lang/foreign/MemorySegment;JLjava/lang/foreign/MemorySegment;)V+142 java.base@22.0.1
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH+0x000007f801087c00.invokeStaticInit(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V+20 java.base@22.0.1
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH+0x000007f80108a400.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;ILjava/lang/Object;)V+72 java.base@22.0.1
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH+0x000007f801089c00.invoke_MT(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+27 java.base@22.0.1
j  com.github.yqy7.ffmdemo.CocoaTest.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+144
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub 0x0000000138ffc154

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr: 0x000003fda9bf7c08

Registers:
 x0=0x0000000139140cc0  x1=0x00000002007a938d  x2=0x0000000000000040  x3=0x0000000139140cc0
 x4=0x0000000000000004  x5=0x0000000046000000  x6=0x000000070f8c61c8  x7=0x00000000000000d0
 x8=0x00000002007a9000  x9=0x00000002007a944e x10=0x6ae1000139140cc0 x11=0x0000000000000001
x12=0x0000000000000000 x13=0x00006000008daa10 x14=0x910003fda9bf7bfd x15=0x000003fda9bf7bf8
x16=0x000003fda9bf7bf8 x17=0x0000000209de6c08 x18=0x0000000000000000 x19=0x0000000139140cc0
x20=0x0000000000000040 x21=0x0000600000896060 x22=0x000000011844fa58 x23=0x0000000000000200
x24=0x000000016be926b8 x25=0x00000000000000e0 x26=0x000000011844fc00 x27=0x0000000000000000
x28=0x000000010c808200  fp=0x000000016be92400  lr=0x00000001a3af5c10  sp=0x000000016be923d0
pc=0x000000019fe0dc20 cpsr=0x0000000020001000

I also noticed that the second parameter of addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask is a block, and I tried to manually create a block, but it still failed.
public static MemorySegment handlerMemorySegment() throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException {
        MethodHandle handlerNSEvent = MethodHandles.lookup().findStatic(CocoaTest.class, "eventHandler",
                MethodType.methodType(void.class, MemorySegment.class));
        MemorySegment handlerNSEventPt = Linker.nativeLinker().upcallStub(handlerNSEvent,
                FunctionDescriptor.ofVoid(ADDRESS), Arena.global());
        System.out.println(handlerNSEventPt);

        MemoryLayout blockLayout = MemoryLayout.structLayout(ADDRESS.withName("isa"),
                JAVA_INT.withName("flags"),
                JAVA_INT.withName("reserved"),
                ADDRESS.withName("funPtr"),
                ADDRESS.withName("desc")
        );
        VarHandle isaVarHandle = blockLayout.varHandle(PathElement.groupElement("isa"));
        VarHandle flagsVarHandle = blockLayout.varHandle(PathElement.groupElement("flags"));
        VarHandle reservedVarHandle = blockLayout.varHandle(PathElement.groupElement("reserved"));
        VarHandle funcPtrVarHandle = blockLayout.varHandle(PathElement.groupElement("funPtr"));
        VarHandle descPtrVarHandle = blockLayout.varHandle(PathElement.groupElement("desc"));

        MemoryLayout blockDescLayout = MemoryLayout.structLayout(
                JAVA_LONG.withName("reserved"),
                JAVA_LONG.withName("block_size")
        );

        MemorySegment blockDescSegment = Arena.global().allocate(blockDescLayout);
        VarHandle descReservedVarHandle = blockDescLayout.varHandle(PathElement.groupElement("reserved"));
        VarHandle descBlockSizeVarHandle = blockDescLayout.varHandle(PathElement.groupElement("block_size"));
        descReservedVarHandle.set(blockDescSegment, 0, 0);
        descBlockSizeVarHandle.set(blockDescSegment, 0, 16);

        MemorySegment blockSegment = Arena.global().allocate(blockLayout);
        MemorySegment isaSegment = Arena.global().allocate(32 * ADDRESS.byteSize(), ADDRESS.byteAlignment());

        isaVarHandle.set(blockSegment, 0, isaSegment);
        flagsVarHandle.set(blockSegment,  0, 0);
        reservedVarHandle.set(blockSegment, 0, 0);
        funcPtrVarHandle.set(blockSegment, 0, handlerNSEventPt);
        descPtrVarHandle.set(blockSegment, 0, blockDescSegment);

        return blockSegment;
    }


The si_addr: 0x000003fda9bf7c08 tells you which address was being accessed when the crash happened. You might be able to figure out which segment it belongs to by printing out segments you allocate.

I think you are an the right track with creating a block, probably the issue is the empty segment pointed to by isa. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an Objective-C runtime API for creating a block out of a C function pointer though. You might consider having your own small Objective-C library that accepts a C function pointer, and creates and returns a block that calls that pointer.

@Jorn Vernee, Thank you for your answer. I resolved the issue by modifying the following code:
MemorySegment isaSegment = foundationSymbolLookup().find("_NSConcreteStackBlock").get();
